# undefined offset php multidimensional array

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
$tempfiles=array();
    $i=0;
    foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
        $sql='Select * FROM file WHERE name="'.$row['filename'].'"';
        $q=$this->db->query($sql);

        foreach ($q->result_array() as $tuple) {
            $tempfiles[$i]['content']=$tuple['content'];
            $tempfiles[$i]['owner']=$tuple['content'];
            $tempfiles[$i]['last_modified_date']=$tuple['last_modified_date'];
        }
        $i++;
    }


    $i=0;
    $files=array();
    foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
        $files[$i]['name']=$row['filename'];
here:   $files[$i]['content']=$tempfiles[$i]['content'];
here:   $files[$i]['owner']=$tempfiles[$i]['owner'];
here:   $files[]['last_modified_date']=$tempfiles[$i]['last_modified_date'];
        $i++;
    }
```

php error : undefined offset 0 at lines where i have mentioned 'here', whats the problem i cant figure it out?

/i am using codeigniter./

Comment: `var_dump($tempfiles)` after the first loop, see what you have.

Comment: it says array(size=0) empty

Comment: So none of your other code executed, apparently.

Comment: yeah i found it, thanx alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should better check

```
$query->result_array()
```

in first loop that it contains any result or not.

If not, then you should not move further otherwise execute the code.

Again for next code in first foreach, check

```
$q->result_array()
```

if it contains result then move for assigning values in **$tempfiles**.

And for assigning values in **$files**, you should go like,

```
$files=array();
if( !empty($tempfiles))
{
  $i=0;
  foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
      $files[$i]['name']=$row['filename'];
  here:   $files[$i]['content']=$tempfiles[$i]['content'];
  here:   $files[$i]['owner']=$tempfiles[$i]['owner'];
  here:   $files[]['last_modified_date']=$tempfiles[$i]['last_modified_date'];
      $i++;
  }
}
```